# Calculate the near clip plane distance in meters from a certain object - Unity

Tags: unity, camera, frustum, clipping

How do you convert the near clip plane and far clip planes to position units, to be able to find out its  distance to a game object?

Answer (score 0):

The near and far clip planes are already measured in world position units.

```
public struct ClipPlaneDistances {
    public float fromFarPlane;
    public float fromNearPlane;
}

public static ClipPlaneDistances GetDistancesFromClipPlanes(Camera camera, Vector3 point) {
    Vector3 fromCamera = point - camera.transform.position;
    float depth = Vector3.Dot(fromCamera, camera.transform.forward);

    ClipPlaneDistances distances;
    distances.fromNearPlane = depth - camera.nearClipPlane;
    distances.fromFarPlane = camera.farClipPlane - depth;

    return distances;
}
```